# Saving CSV file instead of downloading

Tags: php, mysql, csv

So I have this code to generate a CSV file from mysql database. But however, it downloads the code instead of saving it to the directory for further use (need to send that file via phpmailer).
What changes should I do to make it save the file to the directory.

```
$array = array();
if(file_exists('records_monthly.csv'))
    {
        unlink('records_monthly.csv');
    }
# Headers
$array[] = array("Serial Number","Donation Type", "Amount", "Status", "Date", "Orderref", "DIN");
$serial=1;
try
{
    $s = $conn->query("SELECT c.firstname AS firstname, c.lastname as lastname, c.address AS address, c.city AS city, c.postalnumber AS postalnumber, c.email AS cemail, d.donation_type as donation_type, d.donation_amount as donation_amount, d.orderref as orderref, d.status as status, d.donation_on AS donation_on, d.din as din from customers c, donations d where c.email = d.donator");
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
while($donations = $s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
{
    if($donations->status == 0)
    {
        $array[] = array($serial++,$donations->donation_type,$donations->donation_amount,"Failed",$donations->donation_on,$donations->orderref,$donations->din);    
    }
    else
    {
        $array[] = array($serial++,$donations->donation_type,$donations->donation_amount,"Success",$donations->donation_on,$donations->orderref,$donations->din);
    }

}

array_to_csv_download($array,"records_monthly.csv",",");

function array_to_csv_download($array, $filename = "export.csv", $delimiter=";") {
    // open raw memory as file so no temp files needed, you might run out of memory though
    $f = fopen('php://memory', 'w'); 
    // loop over the input array
    foreach ($array as $line) { 
        // generate csv lines from the inner arrays
        fputcsv($f, $line, $delimiter); 
    }
    // rewind the "file" with the csv lines
    fseek($f, 0);
    // tell the browser it's going to be a csv file
 header('Content-Type: application/csv');
    // tell the browser we want to save it instead of displaying it
   header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="'.$filename.'";');
    // make php send the generated csv lines to the browser
   fpassthru($f);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write directly to the named file rather than to `php://memory` and don't send headers and output to the browser

```
function array_to_csv_without_download($array, $filename = "export.csv", $delimiter=";") {
    $f = fopen($filename, 'w'); 
    // loop over the input array
    foreach ($array as $line) { 
        // generate csv lines from the inner arrays
        fputcsv($f, $line, $delimiter); 
    }
   fclose($f);
}
```

Comment: Alright, but this file doesn't exist on the directory before hand. Because a cron job runs this script once in a month and it deleted the previous file and then writes to this new file.

Comment: What does it matter if the file exists beforehand or not? This code creates a new file.... that's what the `w` flag is telling PHP to do: `'w' Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. __If the file does not exist, attempt to create it__`

Comment: Well another stupid problem occured. It's working completely fine on my laptop, however on my server, it doesn't work and returns bool false if do var_dump($f) , What might be the possible problem here.

Comment: Check file permissions, your webserver user/group may not have write permissions for that folder